# flutter installation not working for windows developement while flutter doctor returns positive results ..windows not connected after some time

Tags: windows, flutter, visual-studio-2015, dart-pub, runtime.exec

I install visual studio  for windows app development with flutter .Few hours  after installation the windows device was being detected  and I was even building windows apps. later  when I run "flutter run" the windows device does not show up or "flutter -d windows" does not work.

Comment: Which Flutter version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.10.0